# Masser for Matanos Levyonim

Tags: purim, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

Can you use Masser for matanos l’evyonim?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6409 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8222.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can but quote the *Mishna B'rura* (694:3); [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) for a practical ruling:

> והנה השתי מתנות צריך ליתן משלו ולא משל מעשר וההוספה שמוסיף יוכל ליתן משל מעשר

i.e. (my own translation, which you shouldn't rely on):

> and, lo, he must give the two gifts [to paupers] from his own and not from *maaser*'s, and the addend that he adds he'll be allowed to give from *maaser*'s