# Can Yizkor obligations be paid from Maaser money?

Tags: halacha, death, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, yizkor

When a person goes to Shul to say Yizkor they obligate themselves to give Tzedaka in memory of the deceased. Can this obligation be paid from Maaser or does it have to be paid from the persons personal funds? (sources please)

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6295 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6409.

Answer (score 5):

No written source, alas, but I have heard the following, if I remember it correctly, from Rabbi *Yisrael* Reisman (of Torah Vodaas and Agudath Israel of Madison, both in Brooklyn). Debts cannot be paid from funds of *maaser*. If one pledges to pay an amount to *tz'daka*, it's a debt, and he may not pay it from *maaser*. However, if one pledges to pay an amount to *tz'daka* and has in mind when he pledges that he's pledging not to pay from his own pocket but from *maaser* funds, then he may do so, as [I think the reasoning went] he has not pledged any amount from his own pocket, so has no personal debt. [Despite the lack of personal debt, he must pay pledged amount, I suspect.] As always, for a practical ruling, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).