# Recipients of Maaser Money

Tags: halacha, maaser-tithes

To what sort of recipients can one discharge his duty of giving maaser money (lechatchila and bedieved)?

Comment: @msh210 heard somewhere maaser was ideally for supporting torah study not for charity. dont remember where though

Comment: ray, I don't see why you say supporting Torah study is not charity. See the question that this was closed as a duplicate of, which is precisely your question: what to do with _maaser_ money.

Comment: @msh210 didnt say it's not charity but it's a specific type of charity.

Comment: @msh210 Isn't this a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/74028/759 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8222/759 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6295/759 etc.?