# Can I use maaser to buy myself (kosher) books and clothes?

Tags: maaser-tithes

Similiar to this question: [Can one use Maaser to pay a Mohel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74028/can-one-use-maaser-to-pay-a-mohel)

Would books and tznius clothes be okay?
While shabbos candles, hanukah menorah, or other commanded mitzvot are not?

Could I buy some books for my shul, and buy some books for myself as well?

Comment: Buying for yourself defeats the purpose of ma'aser doesn't it? And indeed one cannot use ma'aser either to buy items required for mitzvot.

Comment: Yeah, I was making sure. It was in a context where a woman is poor and becomes a baal teshuva and all of the sudden needs clothes, books and objects we do mitzvot with

Comment: If the woman is poor why would she be obligated to give ma'aser?

Comment: @mbloch If buying a sefer you want/need to learn from so you can better contribute to Torah study with others is your reason, then your purchase with Maaser isn't JUST for you and the intention is bigger, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These questions and others are discussed by the major Poskim. At https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/7238 Section 11, Rabbi Eliezer Melamed says that Sefarim for oneself are a no-go, despite some Poskim who are Matir if you write that they are for others as well, but does allow one to use Maaser money for buying Sefarim (or other things) for a Shul, provided the person did not commit to giving it to poor people.  Tznius clothing are not discussed, but I cannot imagine that they would be permitted, as they are simply a person's clothing.

What is of note is that he says that in some cases, **if a person cannot afford something specific (like a Sefer they want to learn from) unless they save up their Maaser money for it, that person is Patur from Maaser**, as he/she is considered an Ani (and they would be permitted to buy it).  I'm assuming that this would certainly apply to clothing as well.

And here's an awesome Aruch Hashulchan (YD 249:10) quote to finish the discussion on this topic:

> עוד כתבו דמותר לקנות ספרים במעות מעשר וללמוד בהם ולהשאילן לאחרים ללמוד בהם אם א"א לו באופן אחר [שם] וגם זה צ"ע דא"כ נתיר לו לקנות תפילין ממעות מעשר וטלית ושאחרים יתפללו ג"כ בהן וכן נתיר לו לקנות שופר ואתרוג וסוכה ממעשר ושאחרים ישתמשו ג"כ בהם **ואי משום שאמרינן בכתובות [נ' א] ועושי צדקה בכל עת זה הכותב ספרים ומשאילן לאחרים הא כיוצא בזה אמרו שם על מזון הבנים הקטנים ועכ"ז לא חשבינן לה ממעשר כמ"ש בסעי' ז' וכבר אמרו בזה דורשי רשומות ואל יבא בכל עת אל הקדש כלומר דבהצדקה שדרשו על קרא דעושי צדקה בכל עת לא יבא בזה אל הקודש** ועוד דאם אפילו נתיר לו לקנות ספרים ממעות מעשר מ"מ הרי הוא כאחר והלא יכולים לומר לו אין רצונינו שתשהה הספרים אצלך אלא יהיו בבהמ"ד וכל הרוצה ילמוד בם על כן ראוי להתרחק א"ע מהיתר זה וכן שכר לימוד שמשלם בעד בניו הקטנים אינה בכלל צדקה ממעשר והיא מצוה בפ"ע והרי היא כשארי מצות שאין ביכולת לעשות ממעות מעשר וכן מי שלוקח חתן ת"ח כדי שילמוד מ"מ אין ביכולתו לחשוב זה על מעות מעשר אף שמשלם לאחר בעדו שילמוד עמו [כנלע"ד בדינים אלו ועי' פ"ת ודו"ק]: